# Can I extend Function's prototype in ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, prototype

I am trying to incorporate prototype.js's `bind()` function into my Flash component.  I found [this article](http://jordan.broughs.net/archives/2007/11/resurrecting-actionscripts-delegate-for-function-binding-in-as3) by Jordan Broughs, which gave me hope.  He suggested using this code snippet:

```
        Function.prototype.bind = function():Function {
          var __method:Function = this;
          var object:Object = arguments[0];
          return function():void {
            __method.apply(object, arguments);
          }
        }
```

So, I put that in my class, outside of any methods or constructors.  However, when I try to call bind() on a function, I get this compiler error:

> 1061: Call to a possibly undefined
> method bind through a reference with
> static type Function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're extending the `Function` object's `prototype`. It doesn't belong in a class. It's not a method of your class.

The `Function` object is basically a built-in type, and its `prototype` is sort of its base class. By extending its `prototype` by adding `bind` all objects that inherit from `Function`, which is all functions including the ones you defined, will have a `bind` method that creates a closure.

**EDIT:**

This question is actually a duplicate and has been answered here:

[ActionScript problem with prototype and static type variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565154/actionscript-problem-with-prototype-and-static-type-variables)

And according to that question you have remove the :Function in order for it to work.

Comment: Okay, great.  I was unsure of where to put this code to begin with (I have a lot of experience with javascript, but very little with ActionScript).  So, how do I add this code outside of the class?  Should it be in the same file as my class?  Should it be inside or outside of the 'package' block?

Comment: It's should probably be somewhere at the beginning, where your code begins executing. It shouldn't really go inside of any package. I imagine it should go before any attempt to use it, but I haven't used ActionScript in a while enough to know if that will lead to it to not work, I guess you could test!

Comment: Hmm, I tried putting that code outside my class, but inside the package block, outside the package block, and in its own file, and all give the same error.

Comment: I edited the answer with link to a similar question and a better answer than I gave.